# How to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?

Tags: c++

For example, class `Base` has two public methods: `foo()` and `bar()`. Class `Derived` is inherited from class `Base`. In class `Derived`, I want to make `foo()` public but `bar()` private. Is the following code the correct and natural way to do this?

```
class Base {
   public:
     void foo();
     void bar();
};

class Derived : public Base {
   private:
     void bar();
};
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Section 11.3 of the C++ '03 standard describes this ability:

> 11.3 Access declarations
>    The access of a
>   member of a base class can be changed
>   in the derived class by mentioning its
>   qualified-id in the derived class
>   declaration. Such mention is called an
>   access declaration. The effect of an
>   access declaration qualified-id ; is
>   defined to be equivalent to the
>   declaration using qualified-id

So there are 2 ways you can do it.

> Note: As of ISO C++ '11, access-declarations (`Base::bar;`) are prohibited as noted in the comments. A using-declaration (`using Base::bar;`) should be used instead.

1) You can use public inheritance and then make bar private:

```
class Base {
public:
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    using Base::bar;
};
```

2) You can use private inheritance and then make foo public:

```
class Base {
public:
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    using Base::foo;
};
```

Note: If you have a pointer or reference of type Base which contains an object of type Derived then the user will still be able to call the member.

Comment: +1: It can be done, but it was meant for granting access, not restricting it.

Comment: I chose this answer as the accepted answer simply from language feature aspect, not from OOD best practice aspect.

Comment: -1 for using deprecated `Base::foo` instead of `using Base::foo`

Comment: Was `Base::foo` deprecated in C++ 03? if it was deprecated on C++ 11, i do not understand the -1, because the answer was correct for this moment.

Comment: +1 to negate the ridiculous -1 on a good answer (the only truly correct one here). deprecation means zilch here.

Comment: Note that AFAIK there is no way to make such an access declaration for all elements of an enum: they must be redeclared with `using` one by one

Comment: Does an access declaration prevent us from casting a pointer/reference to an instance of the derived class to an instance of the base and then accessing the "hidden" members? I doubt this is the use case that this feature was meant to cover, but I'm still curious.

Comment: what is when there are two `foo`s, one `const` and one not `const`? how to expose only one or the other?

Comment: Does this include both definitions if foo/bar is overloaded?

Answer (score 14):

There is really no way to do what you want because if you derive publicly from `Base`, a user of the class will always be able to:

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;
b.bar();
```

It isn't "correct or natural" to make public base class functions inaccessible in a class derived publicy from the base class; instead, the base class interface should be refactored such that those functions are not public or are split into a separate class.

Comment: -1 because your assertion that it cant be done is wrong, but +1 because your assertion that it probably shouldnt be done is right

Comment: what about inverse - deriving through private access and then making required functions public?

Comment: @jamesMcNellis sorry I can't understanding what are you saying, means the answer given by `Brian R. Bondy` is wrong ? please can you explain it to me. I am student and new to `C++`.

Comment: Being pedantic about best practice when the question is about whether or not it *can* be done, instead of just answering the question. It can't get better than that.

Answer (score 9):

First, you have to understand what you want to do from the OOP perspective. There are two completely different types of inheritance:

1. Inheritance of Interface. It is when you do `implement` in Java or other languages that have interfaces as standalone entities, it is also happens when you publically inherit from an empty abstract class in C++. Here you don't care about code at all but want to tell your compiler and everyone using you base/derived classes that this derived class is a special kind of you base class, it has **all** the properties of base class, it behaves **exactly** as base class does to the extent visible by the user of it, and can be used instead of the base class in any algorithms.
2. Inheritance of the code. You have a piece of code in base class that you want to reuse in your derived class. Base class and derived class does not have to be related in any way, you just want to reuse code and that is it.

Public inheritance in C++ is the mix of both kinds, you get interface inheritance and you get code inheritance as well. Private inheritance is a different kind of beasts, you get **only** code inheritance, users of your derived class can not use it instead of base class and from the user perspective base and derived classes have no relation what-so-ever.

```
struct Base {};
struct PublicDerived : public Base {};
struct PrivateDerived: private Base {};

Base * base; PublicDerived * public_derived; PrivateDerived * private_derived;

base = public_derived; //good
base = private_derived; //compilation error.
```

Since you want to change the interface, you **shouldn't** go with public inheritance, by changing the interface you effectively saying that those two classes have different behavior and can not be used interchangeably. So what you really want is privately inherit and then make all the methods you want public and **not the other way around**.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), public inheritance should model "is-a."  What you are saying with `Derived` publicly inheriting from `Base` is that wherever `Base` object is required, an object of type `Derived` will do.

If you requre `Derived` to hide some operations that are available for `Base`, then what you are modeling is something other than "is-a," and public inheritance is not the correct tool.

What you want is either private inheritance or composition, as other answers have detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have this:

```
class Foo{
public:
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void notGonnaSeeIt();
 private:
    //stuff
 };
```

To wrap it effectively you can either do a private inheritance and pass the methods you want to a public declaration like Brian suggested:

```
class Bar : private Foo{
    void methodA(){ method1(); }
    void methodB(){ method2(); }
    //more stuff
};
```

or you can wrap it with a decorator

```
template<class T>
class Bar{
public:
    Bar(T *_input) : m_Input(_input){}
    void methodA() { m_Input->method1(); }
    void methodB() { m_Input->method2(); }
    //whatever else you need/want
private:
    T* m_Input;
};
```

Personally, I prefer the template way as it allows you to do the same thing with any class which inherits from `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to treat it as the base class later and only need some functions of the base class, you could use composition rather than inheritance? (C# is my first language, but you get the idea)

```
class Base {
    public void foo();
    public void bar();
};

class Derived {
    private Base _base;

    public void bar() {
        _base.bar();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

with C++ 11 you could do the following:

```
class Base {
   public:
     void foo();
     void bar();
};

class Derived : public Base {
   private:
     using Base::bar;  

};
```

This ensures that Base::bar() is not accessible from outside the Derived class. It's ofcourse still accessible from outside the Base class.