# Can I make a public member variable private in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I want to do make a public member in a base class private in a derived class, like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int   x;
    int   y;
};

class B : public A {
    // x is still public
private:
    // y is now private
    using y;
};
```

But apparently "using" can't be used that way. Is there any way to do this in C++?

(I can't use private inheritance because there are other members and functions of A that must still be public.)

Comment: This feels like an awkward design. Even if you can do this for class B, all someone would need to do is upcast to a pointer or reference to A and then they would be able to access the member.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: how to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986891/c-how-to-publicly-inherit-from-a-base-class-but-make-some-of-public-methods-fr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no. Liskov substitution and the nature of public inheritance demands that everything that you can do with an `A` (i.e. its public members) can also be done by `B`. That means you can't hide a public method.

If you're trying to hide public `fields`, there isn't much you can do. To "hide" public methods, you could do something like:

```
class B {
    // x is still public
    int x() { return a.x(); }
private:
    A a;
    // y is now private since you didn't add a forwarding method for it
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, using declaration `technically` allows you to do so.

You have to use `using A::y` instead of `using y`

However please seriously evaluate if doing this makes a design sense.

Few observations:

1. Your class should not have public data. That should be avoided as far as possible. If you stick to this design principle, you may not have a need to make it private in derived class.
2. Stick to [LSP](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf). If a base class has public method, and unless you are doing private inheritance, clients will be confused if the derived class makes the base class method private with such using declarations.