# Any way to make a base class's const methods public and non-const methods private?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a class subclassing a vector

```
class A : private vector<int>
{
};
```

This make all methods in `vector` private in class `A`. I'd like to make the const methods in `vector`, like `size()`, public; and non-const methods, like `push_back()`, private. How to implement it?

Comment: It's not a good idea to inherit from standard library containers; use composition instead.

Comment: @Beta Note that OP is using *private* inheritance, which is more similar to composition and doesn't imply substitutability.

Comment: A very simple solution would be an internal cast like `vector<int> const& as_vector() const { return *this; }`. The user could `const_cast` the constness away, but this would violate the (implicit) contract. (Similarly, a C-style cast can convert your `A` type to a `vector<int>` by ignoring the accessability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *using-declaration* to (re)introduce the names of inherited functions, placing them in a public "section" will make all function overloads in the referred class with that name publicly accessible:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A : private std::vector<int>
{
public:
    using vector::size;

    A(vector p)
        : vector(std::move(p))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a({1,2,3,4});
    std::cout << a.size();
}
```

Note: I'm using `vector`, the *injected-class-name* of `vector<int>`, which is inherited to `A`. It is not necessary to explicitly type the template arguments.

---

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986902/420683) of the related question ["How to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986891/how-to-publicly-inherit-from-a-base-class-but-make-some-of-public-methods-from-t?rq=1) shows the same technique. That should be a hint to search for an answer first ;) Note, however, that  answer uses *access-declarations*, which have been deprecated in C++03 and I can find no sign of them in C++11 (i.e. don't use them, prefer a *using-declaration* as shown here).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using direct inheritance, encapsulate using the bridge pattern.

[bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)

Comment: -1: You provide nothing more than a link. Also, you seem to be confusing bridge pattern with an adapter pattern.

Comment: an adapter is for exchanging types. That would not be helpful here.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. However, my advice that you should expand your answer a little still stands here.

Comment: I can only lead a horse to water. I cannot make him drink. :P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a typedef to a const vector: `typedef const std::vector<int> A;`

This allows user to declare objects like `A val;` and will disable access to non-const methods. (calling them will cause compile-time error)

The disadvantage is that they aren't different types, so you can pass objects of type `A` to functions that expect `const std::vector<int>`. If having two separate types is what you require, then you have to wrap every method manually with delegation (C++ should have had strong typedefs already :-( )