# C++ change access for member function with overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

My question is related to this one: [How to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986891/how-to-publicly-inherit-from-a-base-class-but-make-some-of-public-methods-from-t), but my case is a little more complex as I want to change the access for overloaded/template functions:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    public:
        void fun(int);         //1
        void fun(float);       //2

        void fun(T);           //3

        template<typename U>   //4
        void fun(U);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Derived : private Base<T1>
{
    public:
        //change access specifier here for:
        //1 - make fun(int) available 
        //2 - fun(float) is really evil and it should not be accessible!
        //3 - make fun(T1) == Base::fun(T) available
        //4 - make template<typename U> void Base::fun(U) available 
};
```

I've tried the method from previous answer to make some function public, but I get this error:

```
ISO C++11 does not allow access declarations; use using declarations instead
```

How can I use `using` to make only the selected functions (1, 3 and 4) available for users of `Derived`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Armen and Jarod pointed out, `using` will bring all `fun`'s in the derived class. Jarod though had a great idea: `delete` the evil function! Combining their answers I got this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Derived : private Base<T1>
{
    public:
        using Base<T1>::fun;
        void fun(float) = delete;
};
```

which does exactly what I wanted originally!

Answer (score 3):

You can either make all entities with the name *fun* available, or none of them. To do so, write:

```
public:
     using Base::fun;
```

Comment: Is it not possible to keep private the evil fun(float) one without changing its name?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have to forward manually as `using` works as a whole:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Derived : private Base<T1>
{
public:
    void fun(int i) { Base<T1>::fun(i); }

    // Don't show void fun(float); so fun(float) will call the template method
    // or forbid fun(float) by deleting the function
    // void fun(float) = delete;

    void fun(T1 t) { Base<T1>::fun(t); }

    template<typename U> void fun(U u) { Base<T1>::fun(u); }
};
```