# Why does C++ allow access restrictions on public inherited base methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Regarding the question "[How to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986891/)", I have a follow-up question:

I can understand that the C++ standard allows a derived class to *relax* access restrictions of an inherited method, but I can not think of any legitimate use case where it would make sense to impose access restrictions in the derived class.

From my understanding of the concept of inheritance, if class Derived is public class Base, then anything you can do with Base can also be done with Derived. If one does not want Derived to fulfill the interface of Base, one should not use (public) inheritance in the first place. (Indeed, when I encountered this technique in the wild in ROOT's TH2::Fill(double), is was a clear case of inheritance abuse.)

For virtual methods, access restrictions in Derived are also useless, because any user of Derived can use them by casting a Derived* into a Base*.

So, from my limited C++ newbie point of view, these restrictions are misleading (the programmer of Derived might assume that his virtual now-protected method is not called by anyone else, when in fact it might be) and also confuses [me with regard to] what public inheritance should imply.

Is there some legitimate use case I am missing?

Comment: Good question. I think motivation is in ad hoc class tree design.

Comment: Access restrictions are useful because the compiler then requires an explicit cast to access inherited private functions, such casts are easily found with a source code search.

C++ is a system/infrastructure language, so the general policy is if something is possible, then allow the programmer to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Herb Sutter, [Guru of the Week #18](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm):

> Guideline #3: Only if derived classes need to invoke the base implementation of a virtual function, make the virtual function protected.

For detail answer, please read my comment in the code written below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>

struct Ultimate_base {
    virtual ~Ultimate_base() {}
    void foo() { do_foo(); }
protected:
    // Make this method protected, so the derived class of this class
    // can invoke this implementation
    virtual void do_foo() { std::cout << "Ultimate_base::foo"; }
};

struct Our_derived : Ultimate_base {
private:
    // Make this method private, so the derived class of this class
    // can't  invoke this implementation
    void do_foo() {
        Ultimate_base::do_foo();
        std::cout << " Our_derived::foo";
    }
};

struct Derive_from_derive : Our_derived {
private:
    void do_foo() {
        // You can't call below code
        // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        // Our_derived::do_foo();
        std::cout << " Derive_from_derive::foo";
    }
};

// This class is marked final by making its destructor private
// of course, from C++11, you have new keyword final
struct Derive_with_private_dtor : Ultimate_base {
private:
    ~Derive_with_private_dtor() {}
};

// You can't have below class because its destructor needs to invoke
// its direct base class destructor
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
/* 
struct Derive_from_private_dtor : Derive_with_private_dtor {
};
*/

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Ultimate_base> p = std::make_unique<Our_derived>();
    p->foo();
    p = std::make_unique<Derive_from_derive>();
    p->foo();
    p.reset(new Derive_with_private_dtor);
}
```

Comment: Your first example is good, for your second though I'd probably mention that at this point this should mostly be a workaround for older compilers. In C++11 you can simply mark the class itself final which achieves the same purpose more clearly.

Comment: @NirFriedman yes, I know that, I used `std::make_unique` to avoid nasty `delete` stuff

Comment: @NirFriedman and you know, this question is not tagged with C++11. Anyway, if it's good, I think it deserve your upvote :D

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite follow your first comment; I mean yes you use `unique_ptr` to avoid needing to call `delete`, but I'm not sure how that's related to my comment? My point was that there is no need to make a destructor private to prevent deriving, in 11. Also, you use 14 in your answer, but give an example that's only best practice in 03, surely you agree it's not internally consistent? In any case, I only suggested that you edit to include the information.

Comment: I did not know about the Non-Virtual Interface Idiom. With it, protected virtual -> private virtual restrictions are perfectly legit, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding of the concept of inheritance, if class Derived is public class Base, then anything you can do with Base can also be done with Derived.

This isn't really the concept of inheritance; this is the concept of polymorphism. In particular, this is a statement of the Liskov Substitution Principle. But inheritance can be used for various things in C++ beyond just polymorphism. In fact, anytime your base class has non-virtual methods or data members, you are using it to inject implementation or state into derived classes, not only for polymorphism. If the base class has no virtual methods and no virtual destructor, then the class shouldn't (can't) be used polymorphically. You may use a base class where neither will the base class ever be instantiated, nor will you ever use a pointer to a base. Here's an example:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo {
    T double_this() { return 2 * static_cast<T&>(*this).data; }
    T halve_this() { return 0.5 * static_cast<T&>(*this).data; }
};
```

What does this weird class do? Well, it can be used to inject some interface into any class with a data member called `data` (and an appropriate constructor):

```
struct Bar : Foo<Bar> {
    Bar(double x) : data(x) {}
    double data;
};
```

Now `Bar` has methods `double` and `halve`. This pattern is called Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP). Note that we're never going to instantiate `Foo<Bar>` or have a pointer to it. We just use the interface it provides, non polymorphically.

Now, suppose someone wants to use `Foo`, but only wants `double` in their interface but not `halve`. In this case, it's completely valid to make `halve` private in the derived. After all, the derived class is just some particular, non polymorphic type, that does not need to conform to any interface other than what the author wants/documents.

Note that when using CRTP, the base class will typically provide public functions, and you'll typically inherit publicly. The entire advantage of CRTP in this use case is that you can inject interface directly; if you were going to make the methods private or inherit privately you'd be better off make `Foo<Bar>` a member of `Bar` instead. So it would be more common to make something public into something private, rather than the reverse, in this particular situation.

Comment: But `static_cast<Foo<Bar>&>(some_bar).halve_this()` is still legal, even if `Bar` restricts `halve_this` accessibility to `private`, being it `virtual` or not.

Comment: @AndréSassi It may be legal, but it is quite convoluted and not something anyone is likely to do by accident. If the docs make it clear that `Foo` is an implementation detail (which is typically the case in CRTP), then the user should not name it; if the user does then the behavior is not supported. It's not any different than classes/functions in `namespace detail` which is quite common. The goal is to protect against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: I was stuck thinking Inheritance==Polymorphism, which is obviously not true. Thanks for clearing that up.