# C++ virtual inheritance and access to a public virtual method whose implementation is in a class whose inheritance is protected

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I am using a virtual inheritance to create a class EditablePrimeNumberSet (a set of prime numbers) that inherits the class EditableNumberSet (a set of integers that can be incremented) while only exposing the base class NumberSet (a set of number).
(I don't want my class to expose the method add that will lead to a set that do not contain only prime numbers)

remark : it is just a simple example. I actually do not work on prime numbers. This example was just devised to illustrate the problem I am facing.

My problem is that, when I want to call the virtual method contains44 on a EditableNumberSet variable, I need to static_cast it to avoid a compilation error. It looks like the compiler finds that the direct implementation is tractable because it knows the actual type of my object but then discovers that this method is not accessible. So, actually, I am not stuck but find it curious and not elegant to do such static_cast. Are there some tips to improve my code ?

```
using namespace std;

class NumberSet {
public :
    int size() {return myList.size();}
    virtual bool contains44()
    {
      cout << "in base method\n";
      return myList.count(44)>0;
    };
protected :
    set<int> myList;
};

class EditableNumberSet : public virtual NumberSet {
public :
    void add(int i) {myList.insert(i);}
    bool contains44() override
    {
        cout << "in inherited method\n";
        return false;
    } // 44 is not a prime number
};

class EditablePrimeNumberSet: public virtual NumberSet, protected EditableNumberSet {
public :
    void addNearestPrimeNumber(int i)
    {
        int j=0;
        //code that set j to the nearest prime number next to i...
        add(j);
    }
};

int main()
{
    EditablePrimeNumberSet listPN;
    listPN.addNearestPrimeNumber(45);
    listPN.NumberSet::contains44(); //  use base class method implementation
    static_cast<NumberSet &>(listPN).contains44(); // use derived class method implementation
    listPN.contains44(); //  error: ‘virtual bool EditableNumberSet::contains44()’ is inaccessible within this context
}
```

Comment: What compilation error? [Edit] to show it. You should not need to cast here. It seems you do because you inherit the base and its method as `protected` in `EditableNumberSet`. Is that intended? If so, why not just redeclare the method as `public` in `EditablePrimeNumberSet`?

Comment: The answers here explain how you can use `using` to change accessibility of base functions: [How to publicly inherit from a base class but make some of public methods from the base class private in the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986891/how-to-publicly-inherit-from-a-base-class-but-make-some-of-public-methods-from-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose a single name from the protected class, you can use a `using` declaration:

```
class EditablePrimeNumberSet : public virtual NumberSet, protected EditableNumberSet {
public:
    using EditableNumberSet::contains44; // Expose EditableNumberSet::contains44 as 
                                         // part of EditablePrimeNumberSet's public interface

    void addNearestPrimeNumber(int i)
    {
        int j = 0;
        //code that set j to the nearest prime number next to i...
        add(j);
    }
};
```

Then when you call `listPN.contains44()` you invoke the inherited method.